# Force Init process to wait in Linux

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Is it possible forcing the Init process to wait in Linux? Would it be safe to do so? 
In my exercise we implement a new scheduling policy that should be active only if the Init process waits
(Linux version is 2.4

Comment: I don't get the point here. Wait on what ? The process with pid 1 get's some special kernel protection (you for example can't SIGKILL it). So waiting initiated from the outside (with for example SIGSTOP) won't work in init. Can you explain what you exact question is, so that I can give you a better answer.

Comment: In my exercise, i should fork 15 processes, change their scheduling policy to the newly defined policy and observe their behaviour
*i'm sorry, hit Enter by mistake, will write the full description in the next comment

Comment: A process that had its policy changed to the new policy should run only when the active/expired arrays in the runqueue are empty, thus, the Init process should be in "wait" state. I don't intend to kill Init, just force it to wait so i can better control my program for testing purposes. I hope this is clearer now, please do tell me if its not

Comment: Why don't you write your own init program that does that for testing?

Comment: Since then I've seen that the Init process waits on its own many times without any special intervention.
Thank you for your help